# How to simplify this expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

here is a transfer function `tf`, the ω has been subsituded with a specific solve. I want to calculate its phase margin and simplify it.

```
tf=-((I Sqrt[2])/(Sqrt[-k^2 + k Sqrt[4 + k^2]] (1 + (I Sqrt[-k^2 + k Sqrt[4 + k^2]])/(Sqrt[2] k))))
phaseMargin = Arg[tf] + \[Pi] // FullSimplify
```

the MMA didn't give out a satisfying result, well my friend who is good at math simplify it in hand, give out a pretty result of

```
ArcCos[Sqrt[1 + k^2/4] - k/2]
```

I believe MMA is capable of handling this, could anyone help me?

I still have a litte wish. I'm for engineering (IC Design) insted of theoretical reserach, hoping to use MMA to make up for my mathematical shortcomings. Is there any common methodology to process these sort of expression (symbolic expression in s/z domain, solve equation, integrate the spectrum...)? I would be very grateful if anyone could help me！

---

Ps. the initial transfer function is `tfInitial = 1/s*(1/(s/k + 1)) /. s -> I*ω`,  solve `Abs[tfInitial ]==1`, then `ToRadicals`, substidute the `ω` with the solve, then get the `tf` in my post above.

---

Update:

The `tf` above is revised now. Here is the complete code:

when I try to solve this equation, I got `Root[-k^2 + k^2 #1^2 + #1^4 &, 2]`

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
tf = 1/s*(1/(s/k + 1)) /. s -> I*\[Omega];
eq = Abs[tf] == 1;
sol = Assuming[{k < 0 && \[Omega] > 0}, SolveValues[eq, \[Omega]]]
```

Actually, the answer should be the 3rd `Root`

```
sol = ToRadicals[Root[sol[[1, 1]], 3]]
tf = tf /. \[Omega] -> sol;
phaseMargin=[Arg[tf] + \[Pi]]
```

Why I got the 2nd Root? is my `Assuming` wrong?

Comment: I am guessing some domain information about `k` is likely needed. With no information about k the result is complicated, with `FullSimplify[Arg[tf] + \[Pi],k>0]` the result is simply `Pi` What do you know, or are assuming, about the domain of `k`?

Comment: k represents the second pole of this system, k‘s value is supposed to be located in the right complex plane. Or simplify, a real k>0 is fine. I noticed that when k>0, result in Pi. I don't know why, while I dont think this is right.

Comment: when a real k>0the result is Pi... it's right. How about when k is complex number?

Comment: To address your general question: Yes, Mma is (in principle) capable of doing all that. However, one has to learn its parts indicated as "Algebraic manipulations" "Calculus" and maybe something else. There is no easy way of doing all you wish without investing time. But there is good news: investing pays off.

Answer (score 1):

For positive real k, the complex expressions contains no non-real term, but is located in the branch cut of the square root

```
tf = (I*Sqrt[2])/  (Sqrt[-k^2 - Sqrt[k^2 + 4]*k]*(1 - (I*Sqrt[-k^2 - Sqrt[k^2 + 4]*k])/ (Sqrt[2]*k)))//FullSimplify

phaseMargin = FullSimplify[Arg[tf] + Pi]/.
{ Sqrt[(-1)*a_ b___]:> {I Sqrt[a b],-I Sqrt[a b]}}

Out=1/2 (k + Sqrt[4 + k^2] + I Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-k (k + Sqrt[4 + k^2])])

  {\[Pi] +  Arg[k + Sqrt[4 + k^2] - Sqrt[2] Sqrt[k (k + Sqrt[4 + k^2])]],
   \[Pi] +  Arg[k + Sqrt[4 + k^2] + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[k (k + Sqrt[4 + k^2])]]}
```

So the Arg is undefined. As always in these Fourier inversion problems, k has to be shifted away from the cut with small imaginary part in order to get well defined integrals with sensible limit on the cut for real k.

Comment: Thank you for you reply! You are right, in that situation k couldn't be a real number. Now I revised my post. I converted the solve ```ToRadicals``` without considering the order, which caused the problem. Now I post the complete code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I tried, I got a simplified result of `ArcTan[]`

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
(*solve the ω when Abs[tf]==1*)
tf = 1/s*(1/(s/k + 1)) /. s -> I*ω;
eq = Abs[tf] == 1;
sol = Assuming[{k < 0, ω > 0}, SolveValues[eq, ω]];
(*the order of Root and ToRadicals is not match (BUG?)*)
solRoot3 = ToRadicals[Root[sol[[1, 1]], 3]];
(*calculate the Phase when Abs[tf]=1*)
tfs = tf /. ω -> solRoot3;
reim = ComplexExpand[ReIm[tfs]] // Simplify;
(*phaseMargin = phase@(mag=1)+π*)
pm = Assuming[{k > 0}, FullSimplify[ArcTan[reim[[2]]/reim[[1]]] + π]]
```

Result is

```
π + ArcTan[Sqrt[k] (1 + 1/2 k (k + Sqrt[4 + k^2]))^(1/4)]
```

But this is not perfect result, the perfect Result is

```
pmPrettyResult = ArcCos[Sqrt[1 + k^2/4] - k/2];
```

I tried to verify if these 2 phaseMargins are equal

```
N[pm - pmPrettyResult /. k -> {0.1, 0.2, 1 , 2}, 12]
```

Result, 2π diffrence is resonable, they are not that accurate because of irrational calculation?

```
{3.14159, 3.14159, 3.14159265359, 3.14159265359}
```

I still have no clue to get this pretty result, sad